# Mutex never reached under match when use from thread

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a TCP client implemented with `tokio`. I have 3 threads there, also I have 2 `Mutex<VecDeque>` queues (where Mutex is `tokio::sync::Mutex`). The issue is that my locks processed incorrectly. When I put some `println!` inside `match` of `handle_write` method, I see only this println! output -> "I see output here", but no println! output from `match`:

```
async fn handle_write(&mut self) {
    let stream = Arc::clone(&self.stream);
    let session = Arc::clone(&self.session);
    let output_queue = Arc::clone(&self.output_queue);

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        println!("I see output here");
        match stream.lock().await.as_mut() {
            Some(stream) => {
                println!("Stream exists -> BUT no output");
                let packet = match output_queue.lock().await.pop_front() {
                    Some(packet) => match session.lock().await.header_crypt.as_mut() {
                        Some(header_crypt) => header_crypt.encrypt(&packet),
                        _ => packet,
                    },
                    _ => vec![],
                };

                if !packet.is_empty() {
                    println!("My packet do not displayed: {:?}", &packet);
                    stream.write(&packet).await.unwrap();
                    stream.flush().await.unwrap();
                }
            },
            _ => {
                println!("No stream -> ALSO no output");
            },
        };
    }).await.unwrap()
}
```

at the same time I see output here ("Stream exists -> and I see output !"):

```
async fn handle_read(&mut self) {
    let queue = Arc::clone(&self.input_queue);
    let stream = Arc::clone(&self.stream);
    let session = Arc::clone(&self.session);

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        match stream.lock().await.as_mut() {
            Some(stream) => {
                println!("Stream exists -> and I see output !");
                let mut buffer = [0u8; 4096];

                match stream.read(&mut buffer).await {
                    Ok(bytes_count) => {
                        println!("{}", &bytes_count);
                        let raw_data = match session.lock().await.header_crypt.as_mut() {
                            Some(header_crypt) => header_crypt.decrypt(&buffer[..bytes_count]),
                            _ => buffer[..bytes_count].to_vec(),
                        };

                        queue.lock().await.push_back(raw_data);
                    },
                    _ => {},
                };
            },
            _ => {},
        };
    }).await.unwrap()
}
```

this is how this handlers called:

```
pub async fn handle_connection(&mut self) {
    let packet = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    self.output_queue.lock().await.push_back(packet);

    loop {
        timeout(Duration::from_millis(TIMEOUT), self.handle_read()).await.unwrap();
        timeout(Duration::from_millis(TIMEOUT), self.handle_queue()).await.unwrap();
        timeout(Duration::from_millis(TIMEOUT), self.handle_write()).await.unwrap();
    }
}
```

this is [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6432eb3c26d0f3bcd3e5f6033e4c3a79) (however I do not understand how to allow tcp connection there, maybe somebody can tell in comments ?).

Why this part of `handle_write` never reached ?

```
match stream.lock().await.as_mut() {
    Some(stream) => {
        println!("Stream exists -> do not output");
        let packet = match output_queue.lock().await.pop_front() {
            Some(packet) => match session.lock().await.header_crypt.as_mut() {
                Some(header_crypt) => header_crypt.encrypt(&packet),
                _ => packet,
            },
            _ => vec![],
        };

        if !packet.is_empty() {
            println!("My packet do not displayed: {:?}", &packet);
            stream.write(&packet).await.unwrap();
            stream.flush().await.unwrap();
        }
    },
    _ => {
        println!("No stream -> do not output");
    },
};
```

Comment: What is the type of `stream`? In fact, what is the original definition of the struct you are implementing?

Comment: The playground has no internet connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misusing mutexes.

The *technical* reason is that you have a deadlock: after the lock for `self.stream` in `handle_read()` is acquired, and when new data arrives, you try to lock `self.input_queue`, but it is already locked by `handle_queue()` waiting for the data to be written there by `handle_read()`. Thus, the lock for `self.stream` is never released, and `handle_write()` never has a chance to get it.

The *underlying* reason is that you use locks where you shouldn't. Do not use mutexes for read/write pairs: the write thread may never get a chance to write because the read thread is holding the lock, as happened here. You should use channels for in-memory read/write, and [stream splits](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/fn.split.html) for I/O pairs.

Comment: could you provide small example of how to use split here ? I should create Arc<Mutex> from it ?

Comment: The problem is that an example won't be small. I would split it in `handle_connect()` and pass as parameters to `handle_read()` and `handle_write()`, but there are also other ways to write that.

Comment: could you clarify, what type annotation should be for ReadHalf<T> and WriteHalf<T> ? Smth like TCPStream ?

Comment: when I set TcpStream as T, I got an error "expected `ReadHalf<TcpStream>`, found `tokio::net::tcp::split::ReadHalf`"

Comment: found, ReadHalf should be imported from tokio::net::tcp, not from tokio::io

Comment: Ah, nice, I didn't know `TcpStream` has its own split methods. I meant to use `tokio::io::split()`, but it is preferrable to use `TcpStream`'s methods.